# Etiquette and feasibility of re-asking questions on MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

I've asked a number of questions here. Some are "good" questions and some I could have reasoned through on my own in an hour or two but didn't manage to figure out on my own. Some get quick, good answers, while others get ignored. Perhaps many of them are uninteresting, but for others, I think the people who can answer them probably just don't see them.

It's possible that some (certainly not all) of my questions would be suitable for MathOverflow, but in my initial posts there, not really understanding the nature of the site, I was guilty of asking some too-low-level questions that fortunately people were kind enough not to close, so I'm really gun-shy about posting there now.

How does one navigate around this sort of situation? When is it okay to re-ask something on MO? What are other standard things to do about a question that MSE won't answer and people in my department don't seem to know the answer to?

I suspect the answer will be that nothing I have to ask is really worthy of MO, but thought I might as well ask.

Comment: I suggest you take an example of yours and ask on MathOverflow Meta if it is appropriate, if you're too shy to post a question there.

Comment: There are various discussions of this on meta.MO. See the question tagged math-stackexchange to find some of them.

Comment: Also [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo).

Comment: You could also consider offering bounty for some of those questions. It does not always work, but sometimes it does.